# What are “dukes” or “chiefs” in the text of Genesis 36?

Tags: genesis, esau

We read the usual genealogies in Genesis 36, of Esau’s family and Seir the Horite’s, and then some of the names are repeated as “duke” or “chief” (depending on the translation) so-and-so. What was a “duke,” then?

Answer (score 0):

The Hebrew is ַאלָּו ָּף or *alluwph*, pronounced like “aloof,” and having such meanings (when a noun) as captain, duke, chief friend, and governor. As an adjective *alluwph* means “tame” and was used for, of all things, cows—the suggestion perhaps being that these tribal chiefs were docile and trustworthy representatives of an overlord.

Eliphaz was Esau’s oldest and, interestingly, himself not described as a chief, unlike all the others except his brother Reuel: this might mean that these sons served as overlords after Esau, though they are never called such. Some of the dukes are said to have “come of”— NASB has “descended from”—Eliphaz (Genesis 36:16). Others are similarly associated with Reuel and still others, with Aholibamah, their mother.

We might well ask the meaning of this construction, rendered "come of" or "descended from"; it might shed some light on the role of "chief." We can take a clue from the fact that at the end of the chapter, a similar list of Edomite dukes is given (36:40-43). There is only a slight amount of overlap with the earlier list; the only names found on both lists are Kenaz and Teman, as well as—most puzzlingly—Aholibamah (the Seirite wife of Esau). Clearly, then, the second list is not a mere reiteration of the earlier duke list. But why are the names Kenaz, Teman, and Aholibamah here?

Since the second list of chiefs occurs in the text after a list of kings (36:31-39), it seems likely that it serves as a kind of gazetteer of major subgroups and territories within Edom. This hypothesis is supported by the description of the list of chiefs as being “according to their habitations in the land of their possession” (36:43). The latter two phrases are not to be found in the 36:15-18 duke list. This suggests that a dukedom, or chiefdom, was a hereditary post, which came to have land attached.

This would explain several things. First, it would explain why some, but not all, of the names of Esau's sons occur in the second list: Teman and Kenaz essentially were founders of dukedoms within Edom. One king is said to hail from the "land of Temani," Job has a friend called Eliphaz the Temanite (Job 2:11), and there are many mentions of "Teman" as a region of Edom within no fewer than five prophets (see, just for example, Jer 49:7 and 20).

It would also explain why Aholibamah's name appears in the second list. Some commentators have suggested that the name was also a man's name, and while that is entirely possible, it is also possible that the second list of names of dukes was not a list of individual dukes, but of entire dukedoms. Hence, because Aholibamah had three sons, unlike Adah and Bashemath, the dukedom of those three sons was not named after any one of them, but after their mother. If this is true, then it might also be true of "duke Timnah" (36:40): this might have named a dukedom descended from Timna and her son, Amalek (36:12).

Finally, the notion that the second list of dukes was a list of dukedoms explains the meaning of dividing Esau's sons and grandsons into the groupings "the sons of Eliphaz" (36:15), "the sons of Reuel" (36:17), and (what merely appears to be a non-parallel description) "the sons of Aholibamah Esau's wife" (36:18). These groupings again suggest that from early on, the sons of Esau's wives separated (which makes sense, as different wives of the same man typically did live apart) and came to be associated with hereditary dukedoms. These three groupings themselves are not found in the second list of dukes, but two of the "sons of Eliphaz" did later rise to enough prominence to have dukedoms named after them, as did the sons of Aholibamah and, perhaps, of Timna.

All of this is, of course, speculative.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the translation "Duke" comes from the Latin "DUX", meaning originally "leader" and could be a little misleading to modern ears.

Comment: Compare Corona KRN QRN -Horns, MeLeK MLK - Milk, Cäsar - Käse Cheese Сыр. So maybe alluwph - cow is more than just a coincidence or an epithet.